# Notes widget shows blanks after upgrading to iOS 16.2

Tags: iphone, ios, notes.app, widgets

When I upgraded my iPhone 8 to iOS 16.2 -- from 16 or 16.1, I don't recall -- the Notes widget now looks like this:

[image: Broken Notes widget]

If you tap on it, it will correctly open the Notes app and all the notes are there, as usual. I have tried the following to fix the widget, that previously showed recently edited notes:

1. Removed and readded from the home screen.
2. Edited, to change the notes folder from which it searches.
3. Upgraded to iOS 16.3.

Nothing has worked, so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem like yours. The only way I found to fix it was remove the **native** Notes app and install it again.

After that, the widget started to show notes again.

Note that deleting the native App will delete **local data**, but **not** that ones saved at iCloud. After you install it again, the notes saved at iCloud will be downloaded automatically.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the widget, but many of my Notes — which are still all on iCloud — fail to sync.

Comment: That's weird, 'cause I did this today to test it again and all my icloud data was synced flawlessly. Try to turn off and turn on your iphone.

Comment: Power cycling corrected the sync; thank you :) Unfortunately, now the widget is broken again!

Comment: Well, I suggest you to delete both of them, App and widget, power cycle and install them after that. This should solve the problem.