# Notes app doesn’t sync all notes from iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud, data-synchronization, notes.app

To fix my [Notes widget problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/453901/100041), I deleted the app from my iPhone 8 and reinstalled it, hoping it would resync with my iCloud account.

I did resync, but not completely. There are still plenty of notes — my most accessed and used, especially — that don’t get downloaded.

How can I forcibly resync my Notes app with the contents of my iCloud account?

Comment: Have you confirmed what is in iCloud by visiting www.icloud.com and viewing your iCloud Notes?

Comment: Yes, indeed. It’s all there on icloud.com… In my other question, it was suggested to power cycle my phone. That seems to have corrected the sync, but now the widget is broken again!!